# Beautifulsoup - Pass variables in soup.find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
result = soup.find('span', {'id': 'dlROA_ctl35_lblROALINE'}).get_text()
```

I want to do the same thing as above by using variables to make it dynamic. I am using the following piece of code, but it does not work:

```
i = 135
idstring = 'dlROA_ct'+str(i)+'_lblROALINE'
dict1 = {'id': idstring}
result = soup.find('span', dict1).get_text()
```

I am getting the error: “AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'”

Comment: Do not call your variable `dict`, it overrides the built-in Python `dict` class

Comment: well, I changed it to dict1, it still shows the same error.. thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: Well it's likely because your original string has `l35` as in the letter `l`, not a string representation of the integer `135`

Comment: ahh... that was so silly of me.. thanks for pointing that out..!!

Comment: Does your first bit of code error also?  If it does then it's because the soup does not contain the span you are looking for.  If it does not, then you need to edit i to be 35, not 135, and put the l back in `'dlROA_ct'` so it's `'dlROA_ctl'`

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you are attempting to set up to use an iterator to find all occurrences of the spans containing that string.  You can do that if you like, but a better solution would be to pass in a regular expression like the following:

```
import re

results = soup.find_all('span', {'id': re.compile('dlROA_ctl\d+_lblROALINE')})
for result in results:
    print(result.get_text())
```

For a quick reference on regular expressions I recommend https://regex101.com

To answer the question you actually posed though:

The reason you are getting an attribute error is not because the code is not properly accepting your variable, but because the source code you are turning to soup does not contain the tag you are specifying.

To keep from getting the attribute error you are getting you can instead do the following:

```
i = 35
idstring = 'dlROA_ctl'+str(i)+'_lblROALINE'
dict1 = {'id': idstring}
result = soup.find('span', dict1)
if result:
    print(result.get_text())
else:
    print('no result found')
```

If you continue to get no result found you may want to consider that soup is not what you think it is and may want to look at `soup.prettify()`